# how to define collation in sequelize and postgres

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

How to do

```
CREATE DATABASE XXX  
WITH ENCODING 'UTF-8' LC_COLLATE='fi_FI.UTF8' LC_CTYPE='fi_FI.UTF8'
```

?

dialectOptions in Sequelize